# Quarkus Opentelemetry - Trace propagation

Tags: java, rest, jms, quarkus, open-telemetry

Our application has a flow that involves messaging and REST calls. Flow looks like serviceA -> message -> ServiceB -> REST -> ServiceC -> REST -> ServiceD

When the OpenTelemetry is enabled, I notice the traceid gets shared between ServiceA and ServiceB with some manual context propagation. So I do see the WithSpan working in Service B. However, when the service makes a REST call with RestClient builder to service C, this flow gets a new trace id so it gets separate flow from service c-> Service D.

This only happens when there is a mix of messaging and REST but not when the entire communication is over REST or messaging.

Any specific reason this happens? How do I address this?

Comment: What JMS client implementation are you using?

Comment: What rest client builder?
Can you use one of these? https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client-reactive or https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client

Comment: For JMS, we are using org.amqphub.quarkus:quarkus-qpid-jms. As for the REST Client builder, the runtime class is io.quarkus.rest.client.reactive.runtime.RestClientBuilderImpl which is the rest reactive client.

Comment: It looks to me that there are issues in the context propagation from the received message to the rest client...
Seems that the rest parent doesn't know he has a parent in the received message.
Please take a look at this project and see if it helps.https://github.com/brunobat/quarkus-observability-demo/tree/main/quarkus-observability-demo-activemq

Comment: Thanks. I have used the same to make it work for our JMS flows between services by manually propagating the conteext. However, i am not sure if anything else to be done for calling REST from any of the services receiving data over JMS

Comment: Do you have a sample project that we can look at?

Comment: unfortunately no. The sample you provided in the link above doesn't do a JMS and then REST. Do you happen to have any sample where someone tried doing this? Thank you again!

Comment: Looking into the otel context - i noticed it's different when the flow is on messaging versus REST. Not sure how to paste it here though..

Comment: If you create a new span upon message received, coming from the propagated context, and them make it current, it should continue to propagate...
You might not be creating the Span in the right way, try to 
 
@Inject
Tracer tracer;
//...
 Span childSpan = tracer.spanBuilder("child").startSpan();

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try that though i tried this and also there is a WithSpan around the method already. Separately, i am wondering if this is some kind of a threading issue. I remember having this issue when I was using CompletableFuture to execute something asynchronously, the context was lost (resulting in a new traceid0 as it was only on the current thread. I had to switch to Quarkus ManagedExecutor thread pooling to retain the context between threads. Is it possible that the JMS is in a different thread pool from the one used for REST calls and so don't share the context between the 2?

Comment: Also debugging further on the actual REST call, it appears the call InsutrmenterVertxTracer has a method sendRequest which has the statement io.opentelemetry.context.Context parentContext = QuarkusContextStorage.getContext(context); - it returns null for when called from JMS flow whereas the REST flow has a value here. as the parent is null, a new context gets created. I tried to attach a context to the QuarkusContextStorage but it is looking for a VertxContext which is null.

Comment: I have tried to create a vertx context and executed the REST call in it like below:  io.vertx.core.Context vContext = VertxContext.createNewDuplicatedContext(vertx.getOrCreateContext());  and vContext.runOnContext(v -> { <REST Call>}); -- This is actually making the otel context to propagate as needed but i am getting a "org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.BlockingNotAllowedException" error in the calling service despite the called service returns the data. Any idea what could be causing this? Thank you!

Comment: So i just tried changing the runOnContext which executes the code asynchronously with                 io.vertx.core.Context vContext = VertxContext.createNewDuplicatedContext(vertx.getOrCreateContext());
                QuarkusContextStorage.INSTANCE.attach(vContext, otelContext);
                vContext.executeBlocking(T -> { <code> }); and this works in that i see the trace carrying over to the REST call from the JMS. Does anyone have a better/cleaner way to handle this? Thank you

Comment: Sorry for the delay. So, you are using reactive code... Yes, this last comment is the only solution and you should post it as such.  This is the way to propagate the OTel context on vert.x under Quarkus. In the absence of a previous context you can create a new one and the a duplicated context will be automatically propagated even if you switch to the imperative world and vice-versa.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation! One more q. how can i have the method with this call to wait for the thread to finish before returning the result?